# Crash APK Cardlan QR Reader

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, lollipop

i have a cardlan reader
https://es.cardlangroup.com/products/bus-card-reader-and-validator
is androdi 5.3 Lollipop API 22

works process of the apk is this:

1. scan QR and check internet
2. then, send the number to an http server
3. server respose Ok or Error
4. if is "OK", Music Welcome, Green Light, welcome message and relay ON
5. Else, Music Error, Red Light, show error server messsage

we have 3 problems.

1. the apk crash and minimize the windows
2. when we scan a QR with a text of 17 lenght brakes and crash the apk

any ideas?

```
manifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".broadcast.BootReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".broadcast.CheckConnectivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
package com.example.test.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.cardlan.twoshowinonescreen.CardLanDevCtrl;
import com.cardlan.twoshowinonescreen.CardLanSpiHelper;
import com.cardlan.utils.ByteUtil;
import com.example.test.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CardLanSpiHelper.SpiCallBackLinstener {
    CardLanDevCtrl mCardLanDevCtrl = new CardLanDevCtrl();
    FileInputStream mFileInputStream;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
    int size = 0;
    private static final String procpath = "/proc/gpio_set/rp_gpio_set";
    private static final String open_led_red = "d_26_0_1";
    private static final String close_led_red = "d_26_0_0";
    private static final String open_led_green = "c_5_1_1";
    private static final String close_led_green = "c_5_1_0";
    private static final String open_bee_voice = "c_24_1_1";
    private static final String close_bee_voice = "c_24_1_0";
    TextView qr;
    TextView qr2;
    TextView mensaje;
    String qr4;

    String fraccionamiento = "XXXXXX";
    String URL;
    private CardLanSpiHelper mSpiHelper;
    private TextView spireceiver;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        );
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        if (mSpiHelper == null) {
            mSpiHelper = new CardLanSpiHelper();
            mSpiHelper.setSpiCallBackLinstener(this);
            mSpiHelper.start();
        }

        mensaje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
        qr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qr);
        qr2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qr2);
        spireceiver = findViewById(R.id.psam_tv);

        new ReadThread().start();
    }

    // Inicio de programación del relay
    @Override
    public void receiveKeyCode(String keyCode, byte keyByte) {
        if (ByteUtil.notNull(keyCode)) {
            Log.d("keyCode", "keyCode = " + keyCode + ",keyBtye = " + ByteUtil.byteToHexString(keyByte));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void receivePasmData(String code, final byte[] respondBuff) {
        if (ByteUtil.notNull(respondBuff)) {
            Log.d("respondBuff", "respondBuff = " + ByteUtil.byteArrayToHexString(respondBuff));
            if ("pasm".equals(code)) {
                if (respondBuff.length < 8) {
                    return;
                }
                byte head = respondBuff[0];
                byte dev = respondBuff[1];
                byte cmd = respondBuff[2];
                byte ret_len = respondBuff[3];
                byte end = respondBuff[7];

                byte[] ret = ByteUtil.copyBytes(respondBuff, 8, ret_len);

                byte[] mReadLength;
                switch (cmd) {
                    case 0x01: {    //open
                        if (ByteUtil.byteArrayToIntHighToLow(ret) != 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        //设置波特率;
                        mSpiHelper.setBaudrate(ByteUtil.byteToHex(dev), "2580");
                    }
//                    break;
//                    case 0x02: {
//
//                    }
                    break;
                    case 0x03: {

                        //读数据(spi),获取可读数据长度;
                        mReadLength = mSpiHelper.getCanReadData(ByteUtil.byteToHex(dev));
                    }
                    break;
                    case 0x04: {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            if (respondBuff[3] == 0x00 && respondBuff[4] == 0x00 && respondBuff[5] == 0x00 && respondBuff[6] == 0x00) {
                                return;
                            }
                            String s_msg = ByteUtil.byteArrayToHexString(respondBuff);
                            String value = s_msg.substring(16);
                        });
                    }
                    break;
                    case 0x05: {
                        //写入psam卡;
                        mSpiHelper.writeScData(ByteUtil.byteToHex(dev), "00B0960006");
                    }
                    break;
                    case 0x07: {
                        mReadLength = ByteUtil.copyBytes(respondBuff, 3, 1);
                        if (mReadLength[0] == 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        byte[] mReadData = ByteUtil.copyBytes(respondBuff, 8, mReadLength[0]);
                        if (ByteUtil.byteArrayToIntHighToLow(mReadData) == 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        byte[] tmpbytes = mSpiHelper.readScData(ByteUtil.byteToHex(dev), mReadData);
                    }
                    break;
                    case 0x08: {
                        //                if (ByteUtil.byteArrayToIntHighToLow(ret) != 0) {
                        //                    return;
                        //                }
                        //冷启动复位;
                        mSpiHelper.coldStart(ByteUtil.byteToHex(dev));
                    }
                    break;
                    default: {

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveSpiData(String code, final byte[] respondBuff) {

        if (ByteUtil.notNull(respondBuff)) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> spireceiver.append(ByteUtil.byteArrayToHexString(respondBuff) + "    "));
            Log.d("respondBuff", "respondBuff = " + ByteUtil.byteArrayToHexString(respondBuff));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveUpmcu(String s, byte[] bytes) {

    }

    @Override
    public void receiveMcuConfig(String s, byte[] bytes) {

    }
    // Fin de programación del relay

    // Peticion GET comienza aqui
    public static class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public interface AsyncResponse {
            void onResponseListener(String acceso, String result);
        }

        public AsyncResponse response;

        private String fraccionamiento;
        private String qr4 = "";

        public GetXMLTask(AsyncResponse response, String fraccionamiento, String qr4) {
            this.response = response;
            this.fraccionamiento = fraccionamiento;
            this.qr4 = qr4;

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String output = null;

            for (String url : urls) {
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
            }
            return output;
        }

        public String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String s;
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    output.append(s);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        public InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.1/lectortotem.php?idregistro=" + qr4);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
                //Nueva linea agregada
                 else{
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(String output) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(output);
                String aJsonString = jObject.getString("status");
                String result = jObject.getString("result");
                Log.d("JSON Object", aJsonString);
                response.onResponseListener(aJsonString, result);
                // JSON_RESULT = aJsonString;
                 //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, JSON_RESULT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 //tvResult.setText(aJsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Peticion GET termina aquí
    private class ReadThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            mensaje.setText("WELCOME, SCAN YOUR QR");
            mensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
            FileDescriptor mFd = mCardLanDevCtrl.callSerialOpen("/dev/ttyAMA4", 115200, 0);
            mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFd);

            while (!isInterrupted()) {

                try {
                    if (mFileInputStream == null) return;
                    size = mFileInputStream.read(buffer);

                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        if (size > 0) {

                            //Buzzer
                            callProc(procpath, open_bee_voice);
                            callProc(procpath, close_bee_voice);

                            //Validar conexión a internet
                            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                                mensaje.setText("WELCOME, SCAN YOUR QR");
                                mensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));

                                callProc(procpath, close_led_red);
                                //qr.setText("QR LEÍDO " + new String(buffer));
                                qr2.setText(new String(buffer));
                                qr4 = qr2.getText().toString().trim();

                                // Conexion a internet
                                new GetXMLTask((acceso , result)-> {
                                    //Verifica string de la cadena
                                    if (acceso.equals("ok")) {
//                                                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.open);
                                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.ok);
                                        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                                        mp.start();

                                        //Encender led verde
                                        callProc(procpath, open_led_green);

                                        //Alert y diseño(toast_layout)
                                        Toast toast4 = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lytLayout));
                                        TextView txtMsg = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
                                        txtMsg.setText("ACCESS CORRECT");
                                        toast4.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        toast4.setView(layout);
                                        toast4.show();

                                        //Encender relay
                                        if (mSpiHelper != null) {
                                            byte[] arg = "A_08".getBytes();
                                            //byte[] arg1 = {'B','0','6'};
                                            //byte[] str_arg_len = new byte[4];
                                            byte[] str_arg_len = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
                                            str_arg_len[0] = (byte) arg.length;
                                            mSpiHelper.write((byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x01, str_arg_len, arg);
                                        }

                                        //Pausar hilo
                                        try {
                                            sleep(2500);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        callProc(procpath, close_led_green);

                                        //Apagar relay
                                        if (mSpiHelper != null) {
                                            byte[] arg = "A_08".getBytes();
                                            //byte[] arg1 = {'B','0','6'};
                                            byte[] str_arg_len = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
                                            str_arg_len[0] = (byte) arg.length;
                                            mSpiHelper.write((byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, str_arg_len, arg);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.error);
                                        mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
                                        mp.start();

                                        // Encender led rojo
                                        callProc(procpath, open_led_red);

                                        //Segundo alert y diseño(toast_layout2)
                                        Toast toast3 = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                                        LayoutInflater inflater2 = getLayoutInflater();
                                        View layout2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout2,
                                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lytLayout2));
                                        TextView txtMsg2 = (TextView) layout2.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje2);
                                        txtMsg2.setText(result);
                                       // txtMsg2.setText("QR INVALID " + acceso);
                                        //txtMsg2.append(acceso);
                                        toast3.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        toast3.setView(layout2);
                                        toast3.show();

                                        callProc(procpath, close_led_red);
                                    }
                                }, fraccionamiento, qr4).execute(URL);
                            } else {
                                //Mensaje en caso de que no tengamos conexión a internet
                                mensaje.setText("OUR OF SERVICE, NO INTERNET:(");
                                mensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                                callProc(procpath, open_led_red);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        //Función de los leds
        public void callProc(String procpath, String cmd) {
            writeProc(procpath, cmd.getBytes());
            try {
                //Tiempo de lectura
                sleep(400);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private String writeProc(String path, byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                File file = new File(path);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "write error!";
            }
            return (buffer.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

```
LOG CAT ANDROID

https://encer.mx/logs.pdf
```

We want to fix the bug and the apk can do this

apk kiosk mode - always on top on screen -
internet go offline appears and send a message, go online dessapears message
we can scan a QR with +17 lenght

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't use off-site links to logcat files as they may disappear/be blocked, just add the relevant portion to your question.  Please read: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004)